# Automatically Copy Cells to Another Worksheet Based on Specific Words

Tags: excel, vba

When the word "Overdue" appears in a cell (in column H), I want the name (in column A) and the date (in column F) in that row to automatically copy and paste into another worksheet (named HomePage) and appear in column C12 and E12.

I have the following code, but it's cutting and pasting the entire row. I just want a copy and paste of the name and date to my HomePage.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change (ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Column = 8 Then
    If Target.Value = "Overdue" Then
      R = Target.Row
      Rows(R).Cut
      Worksheets("HomePage").Select
      With ActiveSheet
         lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
         .Cells(lastrow, 1).Select
         .Paste
      End With
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: use IsEmpty() function to exclude the empty cells

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want two cells, why copy and paste? Just assign the values directly.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim R As Long
    If Target.Column = 8 Then
        If Target.Value = "Overdue" Then
            With Sheets("Homepage")
                R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                .Cells(R, 3) = Target.Offset(0, -7) ' Column C = Column A
                .Cells(R, 5) = Target.Offset(0, -2) ' Column E = Column F
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried Private Sub and Sub and neither work. I don't get a debug error. Nothing happens.

Comment: It works for me. What I gave you was a drop-in replacement for the Worksheet_Change procedure you already had, which you indicated was working but was copying the whole row. My code doesn't change the active sheet: have you looked on "Homepage"? Also, since (like your original code) it is built on the Worksheet_Change event, have you tried adding an "Overdue" to column H? It won't fire unless something changes.

Comment: I found my error. Worksheet_Change doesn't fire when cells are filled in by a formula. I'll have to go back to the drawing board and use Worksheet_Calculate instead.

Comment: Well, not all the way back. One way to work with that without slowing your sheet down too much is to put a countif on the range in column 8 and use the calculate event to check just that cell and only run your code when the count of Overdue is greater than 0. Then set the formula in column 8 so it only shows "Overdue" when the record hasn't been processed. Anyway, sounds like you're on it. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

as per your narrative

> I want the name (in column A) and the date (in column F) in that row
>   to automatically copy and paste into another worksheet (named
>   HomePage) and appear in column C12 and E12.

place the following code in **your worksheet code pane**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Column = 8 And .Value = "Overdue" Then
            Sheets("Homepage").Range("C12").Value = Range(.row, "A")
            Sheets("Homepage").Range("E12").Value = Range(.row, "F")
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```